# Revision comparision in PHP

Tags: php, history, revision

Say, I have var1 and var2 both with a string value. Var2 is a revision of var1 with minor changes:
var1:

```
Hello, world1
```

var2:

```
Bye bye, world!
```

Now I want this output:

```
<span class="removed">Hello</span> <span class="new">Bye bye</span>, world<span class="removed">1</span><span class="new">!</span>
```

much like SO's way. How can I do this in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at [Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff) on PEAR.

Comment: Fixed....seems like the "a href" syntax works, but the other syntaxes encode the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

[Longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence) problem. Once I found nice [implementation in Python](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence#Python) and [translated it into PHP](http://github.com/jakubkulhan/plug/blob/e0b6b074910a774a932ec64731089d692f77e594/lib/revision_file.php#L309) (because PHP arrays are quite memory expensive I had to sacrifice speed by using string to hold LCS matrix).